# Как получить строку " \' " в JS?

Tags: javascript, строки, escape

Я пытаюсь заменить все вхождение одиночной кавычки в строке на экранированную последовательность, чтобы например вместо `"New book 'My book'"` получилась строка `"New book \'My book\'"`.
Но строка `\'` преобразуется в `'`, а `\\'` в `\\'`. Подскажите что делать, или альтернативный метод. Код который у меня не работает:

```js
templateBody = templateBody.replace(new RegExp("\'", 'g'), escape('\''))
```

Comment: А зачем?.?.?.?.?.?

Comment: @AlexeyTen не уверен, что это поможет конечно, но вообще это строка будет добавлена в sql запрос, и наличие неэкранированных кавычек ломает его. В тексте могут находится кавычки всех, так что изменить кавычки в самом запросе не вариант.

Comment: ¿А зачем там escape? подставляйте сразу строку, на которую заменить.

Comment: @user7860670 не совсем вас понял. " \' " и есть строка, на которую нужно заменить

Comment: O_o чую очередной SQL запрос собранный строкой вместо подготовленного запроса. Короче, вам это не нужно. Изучайте как правильно делать sql запрос в документации к тому чем вы пользуетесь

Comment: Ну вот, а вы вместо замены на строку `"\'"` заменяете на строку, которую выдает `escape`.

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо за совет, я подумаю над тем чтобы пересмотреть архитектуру кода, но это утиль скрипт для низкосортного использования. Однако в отрыве от контекста задачи этот вопрос стал интересен, так что хотелось бы в конечном счете получить какой-нибудь ответ.

Comment: @user7860670 я наверное неправильно выразился (вопрос исправил), или просто не понимаю вас. Если не сложно, подкрепите свою идею кодом. Спасибо.

Comment: Вместо `escape('\'')` у должно быть `'\\''`. Тогда замена будет на сроку `\'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем ситуация получилась достаточно глупой. В действительности `" \\' "` заменяется на `" \' "`, но js выводит все равно два слеша (хотя символ в получившейся строке один). Это вводит в замешательство.

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать `replaceAll` и заменить `\'` на `\\'`

```js
let templateBody = "New book 'My book'";
templateBody = templateBody.replaceAll("'", "\\'");

console.log(templateBody);
```